# Imagemagick crop transparent image to mask

Tags: imagemagick

So here is my original image (note the transparent border) `src.png`:
[image]

Here's the mask I want to use to crop. White means keep, black means crop `mask.png`: (Note that it isn't necessarily going to be a square. It could be a heart or a star or anything)
[image]

I also have `transparent.png`, which is a fully transparent image. All three images have the same dimensions.

So, running this command generates the following image:

`convert transparent.png src.png mask.png -composite out.png`

[image]

Which is masking perfectly, but now I want it cropped to the size of the white mask area. Using `-trim` is sort of close, but it gets rid of the transparent areas that are inside the mask.

**How can I resize the masked image to the size of the white area in the mask?**

Comment: After masking, just use `-trim +repage`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what you want for the result. Why do you need the fully transparent image?  Do either of these do what you want?

Full sized transparent image with masked area showing:

```
convert src.png mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result1.png
```

[image]

Trimmed to just the part you want:

```
convert src.png mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -trim +repage result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: This support blurred mask too. More info https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha

Comment: What I did does not blur the mask.  Please clarify further and provide and example.  What is your exact example and your IM version and platform.

Comment: Crop, clip and mask are 3 different actions. Additionally clip and masking can support or not support transparency. With -alpha off you are able to use blurred edges in your masked image too. Example you can create 2 images side by side where point where 2 images are meeting can be faded to create smooth transition. Check "halo_mask.png" in https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do, not least why you need a full size transparent canvas. Your command does not give the same results on my **ImageMagick** version 7.

This command may be what you are looking for:

```
convert src.png mask.png -compose darken -composite -trim out.png
```

It gives this - I have artificially added a red border so you can see the full extent on StackOverflow's white background:

[image]

Or maybe you want the trim box from your mask and to use that to crop your source:

```
convert mask.png -format %@ info:
113x113+570+33

convert src.png -crop 113x113+570+33 result.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop a square from picture, you no needs using mask, just crop it:

magick Uq328.png -crop -crop 111x111+570+331 +repage cropped.png

according to https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/